# Error while installing express

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Saw following error while installing express.

I am using node 0.10.17
and npm 1.3.8

I tried `npm install express`

It looks like version issue. Which version is recommended?

```
npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for C:\Users\GAURAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm
-5800-RRPyptXX\1384367930969-0.5868753655813634\tmp.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: a567c2af000ad22dc8f2a653d91978ae1f5316f4
npm ERR! Actual:   4077b08504e56e904990e4cc29e248752fbf211f
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.
js:38:8
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
\node_modules\sha\index.js:85:7)
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"
npm ERR! cwd D:\Project\websocket
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Project\websocket\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried again?  It could have just been a bad download.  You can also clear your npm cache `npm cache clean`

Comment: Seems npm site issue. I got socket hangup now.I should try after some time.

Comment: You can always try a mirror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npmjs.org web site has been having reliability problems both last week and today. As Jeremy commented, this is probably just npm being unable to get the express package downloaded correctly. Wait a while for them to get it up and running again then retry.

Comment: Yep. Seems so. I am getting socket hangup now. Looks npm site is not responding well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an npm issue, try a mirror:

```
npm [command] --registry http://npm.nodejs.org.au:5984/registry/_design/app/_rewrite
```